# Why xcode debug library size is smaller than release library

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, size, release

I'm building a Xcode library project which contains the another static library of size 5.1 MB.

In Release mode, the output library size is 5.1 MB.
But in Debug mode, the output library size is 2.6 MB only.

I'm wondering how the debug library size is smaller than release library.

The Build Settings are:

```
Optimization level:
  Debug : None [-O0]
  Release : Fastest, Smallest [-Os]
```

Any idea?

While using the above libraries in an application and debugging, **it behaves like 'release' mode library only**. I mean, code jumps/skips few statements while debugging. (through F6, F7 commands)

Answer (score 1):

In your project BuildSettings, under the Architecture section, check if "Build Active Architecture Only" is set to a different value in Debug \ Release mode.